# Text tags with embedded widget supporting multiple signers

Tags: echosign

We have Echosign global account. we are trying to support multiple signature in our embbedded widget, but we have the limitation that we don't know email-id of the multiple signer at the time when widget is created. Text-tags maps the signers with the emailid that we have, but we don'thave email id at that point.
Does echosign provide any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think not knowing signer's email id's will have any issues.
Echosign does associate every signer with an email id, but you need not provide it at the time of creation. 
Just have different signers like signer1,signer2, etc. , have different text tags like {{name_es_:signer1}},{{name_es_:signer2}},etc. and whenever they sign, depending on your signature settings echosign will allow them to verify their emailids after signature.

Answer (score 0):

email fields are not mandatory with echoSign. You can simply ignore setting up emails from the API and echoSign by default will place 'signature-block'(that includes a signature field and an email field as an inseparable block) for every signer's you have on your documents. If the same document needs to be signed by number of people, there is an option called counterSigner or so while creating widgets and you can specify just the signers(signer1, signer2..) as tags,
{{*es*:signer1:signature}},{{*es*:signer2:signature}}.... .The desired tags should be according to your business rule. For you it might just be the Signature or combination of name and signature, or whatsoever.

When the first signer signs the document, he has to enter his email (on the default signature block). He then has to log in on his email account and verify the signature. After this, echoSign will automatically pass the document signed by 1st signer to the next signer and so on.